# Python3 - All possible combinations of 3 variables that = x

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I'm trying to find all possible combinations where 3 variables can = a certain number.

```
x = (10,11,12,13,14,15)
y = (10,11,12,13,14,15)
z = (10,11,12,13,14,15)
answer = 45
```

How would I go about using itertools to find every combination where

```
x + y + z = 45
```

In this case, i would want python to print (15,15,15)
But, if answer was = to a different number, like 30, it would print every single combination of x,y,z that would = 45 when added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools
x = (10,11,12,13,14,15)
y = (10,11,12,13,14,15)
z = (10,11,12,13,14,15)
answer = 45
final_results = [i for i in itertools.product(x, y, z) if sum(i) == answer]
```

Output:

```
[(15, 15, 15)]
```

Comment: A little typo: `itertools.product(x, y, y)` -> `itertools.product(x, y, z)`

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! (i did fix the type as well :D )

Answer (score 6):

You can use list comprehensions instead of `itertools`

```
x = (10,11,12,13,14,15)
y = (10,11,12,13,14,15)
z = (10,11,12,13,14,15)
answer = 35

res = [(i, j, answer - i - j) for i in x for j in y if (answer - i - j) in set(z)]

print(res)
```

As pointed out by @RoryDaulton in the comments, the advantage of this approach is that it is an O(n^2) approach combined with an O(1) lookup time for testing, if `answer-x-y` is in `z`. Presorting the three lists, so that `z` is the longest list, should reduce the time needed for this operation.

I did also measure the execution time. The test clearly shows that Paul's code is the fastest:

```
n = 100
x, y, z = map(list, map(range, 3*(2 * n,)))
any(map(random.shuffle, (x, y, z)))
x, y, z = x[:n], y[:n], z[:n]
answer = 4 * n

def f1(): #team Ajax
    final_results = [i for i in itertools.product(x, y, z) if sum(i) == answer]
    return final_results

def f2(): #team Pie
    res = [(i, j, answer - i - j) for i in x for j in y if (answer - i - j) in set(z)]
    return res

def f3(): #team Paul
    xy = sorted(itertools.product(x, y), key=sum)
    xy = {k: list(v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(xy, sum)}
    xyz = [(a, b, c) for c in z for a, b in xy.get(answer-c, ())]
    return xyz

repeats = 10
print("f1", timeit.repeat("f1()", "from __main__ import f1", number = repeats))
>>>f1 [1.741] #team Ajax
print("f2", timeit.repeat("f2()", "from __main__ import f2", number = repeats))
>>>f2 [0.221] #team Pie
print("f3", timeit.repeat("f3()", "from __main__ import f3", number = repeats))
>>>f3 [0.051] #team Paul
```

(It only shows the fastest value for each program)

Comment: This is more complicated than looking at the product of all three tuples but it is faster: this answer is `O(n**2)` but the product of tuples is order `O(n**3)`, where `n` is the length of the tuples.  --I'm sure you know this but it should be explicitly pointed out.

Comment: In a real life situation, I would use the longest list as `z` and make it a set, before I'd run this list comprehension. Would you like me to incorporate your comment, giving you credit for it?

Comment: If you would like to incorporate my comment into your answer, perhaps with more detail from you, feel free.

Comment: Thanks for the timings.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an `itertools.product`, `itertools.groupby` approach:

```
>>> import random
>>> import itertools
>>> 
# create random lists
>>> x, y, z = map(list, map(range, 3*(20,)))
>>> any(map(random.shuffle, (x, y, z)))
False
>>> x, y, z = x[:10], y[:10], z[:10]
>>> 
# choose a sum
>>> sum_ = 40
>>> 
# compute and sort all sums of the first two
>>> xy = sorted(itertools.product(x, y), key=sum)
# and group by these sums
>>> xy = {k: list(v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(xy, sum)}
# use this to look up the matching x, y if any for each z
>>> xyz = [(a, b, c) for c in z for a, b in xy.get(sum_-c, ())]
>>> xyz
[(18, 4, 18), (16, 6, 18), (6, 16, 18), (4, 18, 18), (5, 18, 17), (7, 16, 17), (18, 5, 17), (16, 7, 17), (16, 16, 8), (7, 18, 15), (18, 7, 15), (16, 9, 15), (5, 16, 19), (11, 10, 19), (18, 3, 19), (16, 5, 19), (18, 16, 6), (16, 18, 6), (11, 18, 11), (11, 16, 13), (18, 9, 13)]
>>> 
# validate
>>> set(map(sum, xyz))
{40}
```